# How import textfile into single string

Tags: matlab, text-files

I would like to import a textfiles, each into on item in a matrix or only one string, I tryed with importdata, textread, readtable, etc. but all these functions imports the textfiles line by line.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileread` will import the entire file as a single string

```
text = fileread('filename.txt');
```